# Is it possible to set cookies in the OnInit event and read them on the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

I'm creating a live mockup for a client website, and I'm having some problems getting the design to work.

The site master has a menu that has multiple categories, but they all contain similar content. I need the menu to remember which one was selected. So I tried setting a cookie that would remember which category was last accessed, and leave that highlighted for the user. (I know this probably isn't the proper way to do it, but it's a mockup and I just want to get it done. Brute force is acceptable).

Here is my embarassingly bad code, inlined on the master page:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
  {
      base.OnInit(e);

      switch (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath).ToLower())
      {
          case "category1":
              HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("selectedCategory", "category1"));
              break;
          case "category2":
              HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("selectedCategory", "category2"));
              break;
          ...
          case "default":
              HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("selectedCategory", "category1"));
              break;
      }
  }

// filePath will be "category1", "category2", etc.
public string IsSelected(string filePath) 
{
    return String.Compare(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["selectedCategory"].Value, filePath, true) == 0
               ? " selected" // The class name to add to the CSS
               : String.Empty;
}
```

And the links just call `IsSelected` with the name "category1", "category2" etc.

```
<li class="menu<%=IsSelected("category1") %>"><a href="/Category1.aspx">
```

My problem is that the cookie is always a page behind. If I go from category1 to category2, category1 stays highlighted. If I continue to category3, now category2 is highlighted.

What I don't understand is that when I set breakpoints, the cookies value is being set to the proper page, but it's being read out wrong. Can I not do this at all?

Can anyone tell me what is wrong or a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All cookies you add/delete will be available/deleted only on next request. This is because cookies belongs to a client browser and HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies returns cookies that come with current request.
Consider using Session or HttpContext.Current.Items for this task.

Comment: +1, I never really used cookies for something like this. Didn't consider that it wouldn't yet be in the current request. I switched to using session. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

One way - maybe not the best way - to share some data on the current request is to use the httpRequest.Context.Current.Items container.  Then you can pluck out your values youwant to en-cookie-ize somewhere at the end of your request processing (PostRender maybe?  Is that even an event?)

Answer (score 1):

You are (properly) adding cookies to the `Response.Cookies` collection during `OnInit`, but your `IsSelected` property checks the `Request.Cookies`. Adding a cookie to the response does not automatically add it to the current request as well (as far as I know).

Have you tried looking for the `selectedCategory` cookie in both `Request.Cookies` and `Response.Cookies`, to handle the special case when the cookie is set in the current request? I'm actually not sure this would work, but maybe worth a try?

Comment: +1, it didn't work for what I needed to do, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Cookie handling hasn't changed as much as I have in the 7 years since I wrote this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnetcookies.aspx?df=100&forumid=13312&exp=0&fr=26